# Unable to boot after updates, or installing anything Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

Suddenly after an update, I was unable to install anything or any updates.

I've tried to figure out what was causing it, I am not sure where the issue is but I would like to be able to install any updates.

After this issue happens I am able to go into the terminal by pressing `alt+f2` and recently I found that I can get into the OS using the command `startx` but this is in some sort of limited graphics mode as it only covers 1 of my monitors, and the resolution is not right.

Before I've had issues when starting KDE (like a wallpaper not loading, or no DE at all basically) and have been able to solve that with restarting plasma,
I would do this using `killall plasmashell` and then `plasmashell` but this didn't work and got this error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb could not connect to display.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimallegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb

fish: Job 1, 'plasmashell' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

not sure if this is relevant, but I'm just trying to give all the information I have

While trying to figure out what could be causing it, I also found that `initramfs` had some issues, I am not sure if it actually has issues, or it's something else.

I am kind of out of options and don't know what to do, is anyone able to help me?

Edit:
result of `apt list --upgradable`

```
code/unknown,stable 1.63.2-1639562499 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.63.1-1639448820]
heroic/unknown 1.11.0-beta.3.electron.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.11.0-alpha]
libegl-mesa0/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libegl1-mesa-dev/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libgbm1/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libgbm1/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libgl1-mesa-dri/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libgl1-mesa-dri/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libglapi-mesa/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libglapi-mesa/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libglx-mesa0/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libglx-mesa0/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libosmesa6/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libosmesa6/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
libxatracker2/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
mesa-va-drivers/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/impish 21.3.2~kisak1~i i386 [upgradable from: 21.3.1~kisak2~i]
```

Edit 2:
`apt update`

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Kubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Kubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                 
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                          
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                                                        
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease                                             
Hit:15 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x impish InRelease                                   
Hit:16 https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
19 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

`apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-peas-1.0 libllvm12:i386 libllvm12 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code heroic libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa-dev libgbm1 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa:i386 libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx-mesa0
  libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers
19 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 229 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1.799 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core/main amd64 code amd64 1.63.2-1639562499 [81,1 MB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libegl-mesa0 amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [154 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgbm1 i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [80,2 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [77,6 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [12,3 MB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [12,1 MB]                                                   
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libosmesa6 amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [3.421 kB]                                                     
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 libosmesa6 i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [3.476 kB]                                                       
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libglx-mesa0 amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [204 kB]                                                    
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 libglx-mesa0 i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [214 kB]                                                      
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [83,8 kB]                                                    
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libglapi-mesa amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [81,4 kB]                                                  
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libegl1-mesa-dev amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [53,9 kB]                                               
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [2.056 kB]                                                 
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 mesa-va-drivers amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [3.388 kB]                                               
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [3.524 kB]                                            
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 mesa-vulkan-drivers amd64 21.3.2~kisak1~i [6.036 kB]                                           
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu impish/main i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers i386 21.3.2~kisak1~i [5.761 kB]                                             
Get:2 https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core/main amd64 heroic amd64 1.11.0-beta.3.electron.15 [95,1 MB]                                                             
Fetched 229 MB in 33s (7.050 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                      
(Reading database ... 240115 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libegl-mesa0_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgbm1_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libgbm1:i386 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking libgbm1:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgbm1_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libgl1-mesa-dri_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libgl1-mesa-dri_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libosmesa6_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libosmesa6:amd64 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libosmesa6_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libglx-mesa0_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libglx-mesa0_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libglapi-mesa_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libglapi-mesa:i386 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libglapi-mesa_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libegl1-mesa-dev_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libxatracker2_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-mesa-va-drivers_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-mesa-vdpau-drivers_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.3.2~kisak1~i_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.3.2~kisak1~i_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) over (21.3.1~kisak2~i) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.63.2-1639562499) over (1.63.1-1639448820) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-heroic_1.11.0-beta.3.electron.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking heroic (1.11.0-beta.3.electron.15) over (1.11.0-alpha) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libgbm1:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libxatracker2:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up heroic (1.11.0-beta.3.electron.15) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up code (1.63.2-1639562499) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:i386 (21.3.2~kisak1~i) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.34-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu2) ...
```

After this my system stopped booting properly

Edit 3:

Not sure if this is relevant anymore, but I've found the messages with initramfs, this happens during an `apt upgrade`

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.201.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-22-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_smc.bin for module amdgpu
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-19-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_smc.bin for module amdgpu
```

I've removed some ppa's, not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but I don't think it solves it, I'm also not sure which I will need to **keep** to keep my system working

here's a list of the available updates that I have, So I assume that one of them is causing the problem
[Available updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXgGL.png)

After removing most PPA's I do get a more normal system update screen, with the kubuntu logo and loading updates xx%
but after that is done I get an error saying:

```
[1.241888] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0017 address=0xfedfb000 flags=0x0000]
```

I assume I'm getting closer to resolving it, but it might just be a weird combination of multiple problems?

Comment: Did your update include a video driver or Xorg update?  What video hardware do you have?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not sure if it included video drivers, 
I'll add the output of `apt list --upgradable` to my post

@Nmath I got the issues with initramfs when I tried running `apt install -f` to see if that would fix it, it was logging a bunch of missing firmware with amdgpu

Comment: I don't see anything related to initramfs in your question. If it comes up with `apt install -f` then you need to provide the output of that command.  The one command from which you did provide output doesn't look like the whole output. Please copy/paste the entire output, even if you think it's not important. Do not manipulate or redact parts.  You also did not add the output of either of the commands I asked you to provide.  If you want help with this you must collaborate since you are the only one who can use your device here. Be thorough and don't reply until all actions are complete.

Comment: @Nmath oops missed the first part of your comment sorry, I added the output now.

I cannot recreate the issue I had with initramfs so I cannot paste the output here, if I run into it, I will add it.

I add the 1 line I left back, but that really is all there is

Comment: @GidoSelten In addition to responding to calls for details and clarification, please also take the [tour] to help you settle into this community.

Comment: You have a lot of PPAs. Some are for `impish` and some are for `focal`. These can't coexist. Repos should only be added for the version you are using. Otherwise there will be dependency problems. Remove any PPAs that are not for your distro. You should also remove any PPAs that are no longer maintained or out of date. See [Are PPAs Safe](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629) and [How to remove PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/q/307). If software is available in both Ubuntu repositories and as a PPA - the official repo is almost always the better choice. PPAs don't have the same testing and support.

Comment: @Nmath , thanks I've tried that, it does seem like some progress is being made, but I'm still running into issues, I'm not sure which sources I need to keep to keep my system working (like the Kubuntu one) but I've explained in edit 3 what happened, Thanks already!